Flutter - How to exclude a widget from layout padding(symmetric horizontal)?

Let's say all screens need same size horizontal padding like the picture above so I made a base layout widget that every screen takes it.
class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const BaseLayout({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: SafeArea(child: child)),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseLayout(
      child: Column(
        children: [                    
          Container( // how to make only this one take whole width of the screen unlike others?            
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffFFFF7E)),
          ),
          // the below Rows need to take the padding and it does due to the BaseLayout
          Row(),
          Row()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



However, a widget like the yellow box has to take whole width size of the screen(no padding needed).
Is it possible? or I should not use the layout and give it to needed ones.
Thanks in advance.

No, it's an exception here.
That page doesn't share the common visual characteristics like padding with other pages.
So, it should has a different design from other pages (Reusability can't be applied here).
But if it's insistent need, it can be handled by just a flag variable.
Look at the following widget :
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool hasYellow;

   MyWidget({super.key,required this.child, this.hasYellow = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return (hasYellow)?Scaffold(
      body: // Design that Exceptional page
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200, // what u want
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
           child: child,
            )
        ],
      )
    ):Scaffold(//Design that reusable page
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: child, // all page is padded
      )
    );
  }
}

And that's how you call in each case:
return MyWidget(child: Text('HI, Has Yellow'), hasYellow: true,);

return MyWidget(child: Text('HI,Has No Yellow'),);

Hope it helps.

You can try to use a negative margin.
 Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('This text will not have padding'),
      ),


Not working. Tried -15 and throws an error

yeah. So I don't think it is possible then.
